# Draw line perpendicular to other line in ArcGIS Pro core host application

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis-pro-sdk, perpendicular

I am trying to draw a line perpendicular to a line segment in an ArcGIS Pro core host application.  There used to be a construct point in the ArcMap SDK but it is not there any more.  This is being done in .Net C#.

Is there  a tool for this that Esri has?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Interface you need to use is [QueryNormal](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/topic20285.html). This constructs a perpendicular line.

Comment: what parameters would you use to make it perpendicular to the segment?

Comment: What it says in the help file, if you scroll down you will see a code sample to help you.